# Jolt Transformation - Replace all matches

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I am trying to get a JOLT transformation to work using https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/.

I would like to replace all "master" values with "7.11".

Input:

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "number": "7.11.13898",
      "branchName": "branch1"
    },
    {
      "number": "7.11.13896",
      "branchName": "branch2"
    },
    {
      "number": "7.11.13895",
      "branchName": "master"
    },
    {
      "number": "7.11.13900",
      "branchName": "master"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
      "build": [
        {
          "number": "7.11.13898",
          "branchName": "branch1"
        },
        {
          "number": "7.11.13896",
          "branchName": "branch2"
        },
        {
          "number": "7.11.13895",
          "branchName": "7.11"
        },
        {
          "number": "7.11.13900",
          "branchName": "7.11"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I can't seem to get a transform or shift that works without changing/altering the structure of the data.
Current Approach:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "build": {
        "*": {
          "number": "build[&1].number",
          "branchName": {
            "master": {
              "#7.11": "build[&3].branchName"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2, branchName)": "build[&3].branchName"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Current Output:

```
 {
  "build" : [ {
    "number" : "7.11.13898"
  }, {
    "number" : "7.11.13896"
  }, {
    "branchName" : "7.11",
    "number" : "7.11.13895"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost found it. You need to replace `@(2, branchName)` with `$` and it should work for you.

> The "$" operator means use the input key, instead of the input value
>   as output.

Solution:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "build": {
        "*": {
          "number": "build[&1].number",
          "branchName": {
            "master": {
              "#7.11": "build[&3].branchName"
            },
            "*": {
              "$": "build[&3].branchName"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.